# Qt How to set focus on a QRect

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a Qwidget with a QRect. Now I would like to move this Rect with my keyboard. Which does not work. When trying with a mousePressEvent instead of the keyPressEvent, everything is working fine though. There are no Focuses yet set, which probably is the problem here. But it's the first time I have to work with those and I just can't figure out what to do and how to use them, even after searching online for the last hours.

I tried putting setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus) in my widgets constructor amongst other things, but nothing has worked so far.  Maybe I'm just blind to an obvious solution, but please help? Thanks alot already

my paint event:

```
    void zeichenFeld::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
QPainter painter;
painter.begin (this);

//Avatar:
QRect rectAv=QRect(xAv, yAv, 20,20);
painter.fillRect(rectAv, Qt::BrushStyle::SolidPattern);
painter.fillRect(rectAv, colorAv);
painter.drawRect(rectAv);
painter.end();
}

void zeichenFeld::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_A){
    xAv-=10;
}
if(event->key()==Qt::Key_D){
    xAv+=10;
}
update();
}

void zeichenFeld::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
{
    xAv-=25;
}
if(event->button()==Qt::RightButton)
{
    xAv+=25;
}
update();
}
```

header:

```
protected:
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

Edit: i simply added the setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus); to the wrong contructor. Working now

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a QRect is not a visual class, so if you used the PaintEvent to *draw* a rectangle, then you need to come up with your special way to handle that in the mouse press event.

something like:

YourClass.h

```
protected:
     void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;
     void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;
     void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) override;
private:
    QRect _myRect;
```

YourClass.cpp

```
void YourClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
     if (_myRect.contains(ev->localPos())){
         _isRectSelected = true;
     }
}

void YourClass::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
     if (_isRectSelected) {
         _myRect->setX(ev->localPos().x());
         _myRect->setY(ev->localPos().y());
     }
}

void YourClass::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *ev) {
    if (_isRectSelected) {
        _isRectSelected = false;
    }
}
```

*but* I wouldn't reccomend that. Try to use QGraphicsView with QGraphicsRectItem as it's a visual class. it knows how to paint itself and it also has mouse handling.

Or even better, Qml.

Comment: okay, I'll try it this way then, thank you alot! Just to clarify, the mouseEvent is working fine, my problem lies with making the keyPress work.

Comment: for the keypress a setFocus(Qt::StringFocus) should work. can you provide the result of void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent *) { qDebug() << "Focused!"; } ?